# Doing a point in time restore with CDC enabled; Possible?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore, change-data-capture

I discovered this week, the hard way, that the database restore options `NORECOVERY` and `KEEP_CDC` are [mutually exclusive](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/587277/keep-cdc-conflicts-with-norecovery-and-standby-options).  So, this begs the question.  How do you do a database restore, keeping CDC intact, with both full and log backups?

Doing research on MSDN etc. I cannot find any documentation on restoring a database with `KEEP_CDC` using any other option than a single full db restore with `RECOVERY` specified.

I was able to find one attempt that did the full and subsequent logs without the `keep_cdc` option waiting until the final log.  Only then was the table brought online with the `RECOVERY` and `KEEP_CDC` option.  The result was a corrupt CDC schema [as demonstrated here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1f0a582-01da-4974-a9dc-4b16a279bbab/how-to-recover-cdc-data-from-trans-log-backups?forum=sqldisasterrecovery)

If the intent is to `KEEP_CDC` on restore are you truley limited to a full backup only or is there a mechanism similar to the attempt above to keep it intact during multi-file restors on a server other than the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Data Capture, or CDC, does not require the `KEEP_CDC` keyword when restoring a database to *the original server*.    When restoring a database to a server other than the original server, you can use the `KEEP_CDC` keyword to specify that the change data capture data is retained in the database.  This is by design, and is clearly stated in BOL [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx) under the section entitled "Restoring or Attaching a Database Enabled for Change Data Capture"

This code shows CDC in action both before and after a `RESTORE DATABASE ... WITH NORECOVERY`

```
CREATE DATABASE CDC_RESTORE_TEST 
ON (NAME='CDC_RESTORE_TEST', FILENAME = 'C:\SQLServer\Data\CDC_RESTORE_TEST.mdf', SIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 1MB)
LOG ON (NAME = 'CDC_RESTORE_TEST_LOG', FILENAME = 'C:\SQLServer\Logs\CDC_RESTORE_TEST.ldf', SIZE = 1MB, FILEGROWTH = 1MB);
GO
ALTER DATABASE CDC_RESTORE_TEST
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
USE CDC_RESTORE_TEST;
GO
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db;
GO
CREATE TABLE Test
( 
    ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1)
    , DATA NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table 'dbo', 'Test', 'dbo_Test', 1, NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE Test ADD Data1 NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15'; /* wait for event to be captured */
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_get_ddl_history 'dbo_Test';

USE Master;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE CDC_RESTORE_TEST TO DISK='C:\SQLServer\CDC_RESTORE_TEST.BAK';
BACKUP LOG CDC_RESTORE_TEST TO DISK='C:\SQLServer\CDC_RESTORE_TEST_LOG.BAK';
GO
ALTER DATABASE CDC_RESTORE_TEST SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
DROP DATABASE CDC_RESTORE_TEST;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE CDC_RESTORE_TEST FROM DISK='C:\SQLServer\CDC_RESTORE_TEST.bak'
WITH NORECOVERY;
RESTORE LOG CDC_RESTORE_TEST FROM DISK='C:\SQLServer\CDC_RESTORE_TEST_LOG.bak'
WITH RECOVERY;
GO
USE CDC_RESTORE_TEST;
GO
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_get_ddl_history 'dbo_Test';
```

Restoring the same backup onto the same server as a new database name appears to retain CDC:

```
USE Master;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE CDC_RESTORE_TEST1 FROM DISK='C:\SQLServer\CDC_RESTORE_TEST.bak' 
WITH NORECOVERY
    , MOVE 'CDC_RESTORE_TEST' TO 'C:\SQLServer\Data\CDC_Restore_test1.mdf'
    , MOVE 'CDC_RESTORE_TEST_LOG' TO 'C:\SQLServer\Logs\CDC_Restore_test1.ldf';
RESTORE LOG CDC_RESTORE_TEST1 FROM DISK='C:\SQLServer\CDC_RESTORE_TEST_LOG.bak'
WITH RECOVERY
    , MOVE 'CDC_RESTORE_TEST' TO 'C:\SQLServer\Data\CDC_Restore_test1.mdf'
    , MOVE 'CDC_RESTORE_TEST_LOG' TO 'C:\SQLServer\Logs\CDC_Restore_test1.ldf';
GO
USE CDC_RESTORE_TEST;
GO
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_get_ddl_history 'dbo_Test';
```

Comment: So restoring to a different database, a new database, or a database that will be a mirroring partner is still a no?  I read this same article but it left me wondering about the scenarios above in a multi file scenario.

Comment: You know what... I just had an epiphany... do a full restore with keep_cdc on the new box.  That will build cdc out, then start you multi file restore over the top of it without keep_cdc to do your point in time recovery.  Ok, I'm squared away now.

Comment: Mirroring and CDC is an interesting case.  The SQL Server Agent components would need to be created on the mirror server for CDC to work correctly.

Comment: We've been running CDC on an async mirror for several months.  It's been working great for tbe data warehouse to query the snapshot.  It wasn't until we moved the mirror partner to a new datacenter that all this became an issue.  Setting up mirror and then CDC, no problem.  CDC and then mirroring... not so easy.

Comment: Great thing to know about.  And not something you'd likely think about until it bit you!